# Does the Vue instance loses its old properties?

Tags: vue.js

Does the browser keep showing Vue instance properties even when they no longer exist? Because I've tried to set the instance to 4 making it a number but still the old data and methods don't disappear from the browser

```js
var r = new Vue({
    el: "#test", //gets the element with id test
    data: {
        h2: "saned",
        ha: "<h3>this shit sucks</h3>",
        imgsrc: "image.jpg",
    }, //data section
    methods: {
        fun: function () {
            return "i am " + this.h2;
        },
    }, //functions section
});
r = 4; //the previous data won't dissapear
```

I want to understand how does it exactly work, because I've thought that since the object is no longer a Vue instance the previous instance data should disappear, I was hoping to put a pic showing how it stays, but I can't since it'll be a link anyway and the post won't be good.

Answer (score 3):

Here you created the Vue instance and made `r` point to it:

```
var r = new Vue({})
```

Here you assigned a new value to r:

```
r=4;
```

Though you now have stopped `r` from pointing to it, the Vue instance itself stays untouched and hasn't been destroyed.

Comment: so the browser reflect the state of Vue nd not the object right?

Comment: @serhani ahmed saned The current state of the very Vue instance, since it wasn't changed by re-assigning the previous `r` pointer to another value.